# Office 365 Sharepoint Default Credentials

Tags: authentication, credentials

I am trying to update an internal application that updates a SharePoint list to be able to authenticate using the users current credentials to Office 365 SharePoint. I keep getting a error "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized." Does Office 365 SharePoint not support CredentialCache?

Here is a simple example that I am trying.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ConsoleColor defaultForeground = Console.ForegroundColor;
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        //Office 365 Site URL
        string webUrl = "https://sp_site.sharepoint.com/";

        using (var newlistitem = new ClientContext(webUrl))
        {
            //newlistitem.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, password); works
            newlistitem.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;
            newlistitem.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials; 
            //Also tried just DefaultCredentials - same error
            List spList = newlistitem.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("List1");
            ListItemCreationInformation itemCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
            ListItem newItem = spList.AddItem(itemCreateInfo);
            newlistitem.Load(spList);
            newItem["Title"] = "Test1";
            newItem.Update();

            newlistitem.ExecuteQuery();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Local, by default the managed client object models authenticate users by using their Windows credentials (`DefaultCredentials`).So you don't need to explicitly set the Credentials for local.

But for **Office 365**, you have to pass the credentials:

```
context = new ClientContext(siteURL);
SecureString spassWord = new SecureString();
foreach (char c in password.ToCharArray()) spassWord.AppendChar(c);

context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, spassWord);
web = context.Web;
context.Load(web);

context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: You are correct. I tried every different combination that I could think of, but I could not get it to pass the local credentials. I thought that this would work, but it did not.